# Blazor - staging data for clients

Tags: sql-server, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm getting started with blazor and looking to re-create and existing web page as a learning excersize.

The site is showing data from a database, updated every minute. Multiple clients display this data in graph and tabular form on large displays.

I'm conscious that if we have a large quantity of clients all hitting the database for the same dataset every minute it isn't potentially the most efficient way.

Is there a way to stage the data on the server, refreshed every minute, and anyone who requests, grabs it from the server and not the DB directly?

Planning on using a blazor server and .net 7, database is a MSSQL. There will be multiple datasets based on which pages they request.

Just looking for concepts or reference material to read how best to do this.

Comment: Is the data read-only?  Is the client responsible for page refreshes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where you'll find relevant reference material other than on Stack Overflow.

You can implement what is a singleton data pipeline and share that data amongst a set of clients, but you need to be mindful of threading issues i.e. clients on one thread accessing a list on another thread.  Normal collections, such a `List<T>`, are not thread safe.  In the demo below I've used a `ConcurrentBag` collection that is thread safe.  I've not used interfaces in ther data pipeline to keep things simple.

This emulates your Data Broker that gets data from the database/DbContext.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastDataProvider
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    // Returns an IEnumerable to emulate the IEnumerable/IQueryable a DbContext will return 
    public async Task<IEnumerable<WeatherForecast>> GetForecastAsync()
    {
        var startDate = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);
        await Task.Yield();
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = startDate.AddDays(index),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        }).AsEnumerable();
    }
}
```

The `WeatherForecastService` is where most of the logic resides.  There's no timer, so if there's no client, there's no activity.  The code uses a timestamp to detect if a refresh is required when a client calls `GetDataAsync`.  `CheckTimeAndGetData` ensures only one update Task is ever running. The recordset is materialized into a thread safe `ConcurrentBag` collection.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastService
{
    // The data provider
    private readonly WeatherForecastDataProvider _provider;
    // A thread safe collection to hold the materialized data from the data source
    private readonly ConcurrentBag<WeatherForecast> _forecasts = new ConcurrentBag<WeatherForecast>();
    // A task to hold the reference to the running task
    private Task _refreshTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    // The timestamp of the last time the data was refreshed
    private DateTime _lastRefreshTime;

    public WeatherForecastService(WeatherForecastDataProvider provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
        // kick off an initial refresh 
        _refreshTask = this.RefreshData();
    }

    public async Task<ConcurrentBag<WeatherForecast>> GetDataAsync()
    {
        await CheckTimeAndGetData();
        return _forecasts;
    }

    // This method checks to see if we need to refresh the data
    // and ensures only one refresh task is ever run
    private async Task CheckTimeAndGetData()
    {
        // Check if we need to refresh but don't already have a refresh task runnning
        // If so kick off a refresh and assign the task 
        if (_refreshTask.IsCompleted && DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-15) > _lastRefreshTime)
        {
            var task = this.RefreshData();
            _refreshTask = task;
        }

        // wait for the refresh task to complete.
        // If it's already complete then we just carry on thro 
        await _refreshTask;
    }

    // This method refreshes the collection from the data provider
    // and populates the thread safe collection
    private async Task RefreshData()
    {
        var list = await _provider.GetForecastAsync();
        _forecasts.Clear();
        foreach (var item in list)
            _forecasts.Add(item);

        _lastRefreshTime= DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

The `WeatherForecastPresenter` is the presentation layer object for the the UI: the *View*.

```cs
public class WeatherForecastPresenter
{
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Items { get; private set; } = Enumerable.Empty<WeatherForecast>();
    private WeatherForecastService _service;
    
    public WeatherForecastPresenter(WeatherForecastService weatherForecastService)
    {
        _service = weatherForecastService;
    }

    public async ValueTask GetItemsAsync()
    {
        var list = await _service.GetDataAsync();
        this.Items = list.ToList();
    }
}
```

The services are registered in `Program`;

```cs
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastDataProvider>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<WeatherForecastPresenter>();
```

And finally a modified `fetchData` to use the ``

```cs
@page "/fetchdata"
@using SO75701847.Data
@using System.Timers
@inject WeatherForecastPresenter ForecastPresenter
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Weather forecast</PageTitle>

<h1>Weather forecast</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Temp. (C)</th>
            <th>Temp. (F)</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var forecast in this.ForecastPresenter.Items)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@forecast.Date.ToShortDateString()</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureC</td>
                <td>@forecast.TemperatureF</td>
                <td>@forecast.Summary</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    private Task _refreshTask = Task.CompletedTask;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += this.OnTimerElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;

        _refreshTask = this.RefreshData();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => _refreshTask = this.RefreshData();

    private async Task RefreshData()
    {
        await ForecastPresenter.GetItemsAsync();
        await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _timer.Elapsed -= this.OnTimerElapsed;
}
```

Comment: The data will be read only for all clients. It's a simple graph that is updated every minute for the day/shift. The clients will refresh from the server, and I'm hoping to serve the data from the server and not the DB. I'll implement your answer and have a play. Thanks fo the detailed response.

Comment: This has worked amazinly. Thanks for your detailed and comprehensive answer!