# Blazor (Mudblazor) Table Countdown Property

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, mudblazor

I have a table in a MudBlazor application that contains a value for Stop Time. One of the columns I am displaying on the table is Time Left which is populated by a function that calculates the time left based on the current date and the Stop Time value. I am wondering if there is an easy way to make this value update dynamically, say once every minute. The way I have it setup now you can hit a refresh button, but it is quite taxing and I don't really want to setup a full refresh every minute.

```
 <MudTable Items="ActiveForwards" Hover="true" SortLabel="Sort By" Elevation="0" Filter="new Func<UniversalObject,bool>(FilterResults)">
    <ToolBarContent>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="searchString1" Placeholder="Search" Adornment="Adornment.Start" AdornmentIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" IconSize="Size.Medium" Class="mt-0"></MudTextField>
    </ToolBarContent>
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<UniversalObject, object>(x=>x.DisplayName)">Mailbox</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<UniversalObject, object>(x=>x.EmailAddress)">Email Address</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<UniversalObject, object>(x=>x.User.ForwardToDisplay)">Forward Mailbox</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<UniversalObject, object>(x=>x.User.StopTime.ToString())">Stop Time</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        <MudTh>Time Left</MudTh>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
        <MudTh></MudTh>
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Display Name">@context.DisplayName</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Email Address">@context.EmailAddress</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Forward To Display Name">@context.User.ForwardToDisplay</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Stop Time">@context.User.StopTime.ToString()</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Time Left"><h3>@CountdownTimer(context)</h3></MudTd>
        <MudTd><MudIcon Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Refresh" Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="@(context.User.DeliverToMailboxAndForward ? Color.Primary : Color.Default)" Size="Size.Medium" /></MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Actions"><MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Delete" @onclick="() => HandleRemoveAction(context)"></MudIconButton></MudTd>
    </RowTemplate>
    <PagerContent>
        <MudTablePager PageSizeOptions="new int[]{10, 50, 100}" />
    </PagerContent>
</MudTable>
```

}

```
private string CountdownTimer(UniversalObject forward)
{
    if (forward.User.StopTime != null)
    {
        var timeLeft = forward.User.StopTime - DateTime.Now;

        if (timeLeft.Value.Days > 0)
        {
            return $"{timeLeft.Value.Days}D {timeLeft.Value.Hours}H {timeLeft.Value.Minutes}M";
        }
        if (timeLeft.Value.Hours > 0)
        {
            return $"{timeLeft.Value.Hours}H {timeLeft.Value.Minutes}M";
        }
        return $"{timeLeft.Value.Minutes}M";
        
    }
    return "\u221e";
}
```

Comment: To answer your question: take a look at this answer to a question asked yesterday.  It shows how to run a timer and do automatic updates - https://stackoverflow.com/a/75704414/13065781.  An observation:  You can setup `CountDownTimer` as an extension method to `UniversalObject` and then use it like this `context.CountDownTime()` wherever you wish.

Comment: This is what I needed. If you want supply it in the form of an answer to get credit. The only question I have with the implementation is what the point of _refreshTask variable is. When I implemented it I got rid of that variable and set OnTimerElapsed to => Task.Run(RefreshData). Was there a point to that extra variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple demo page that shows how to run a timer Task in a page.

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.Timers
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="alert alert-info">
    @this.Message
</div>

@code {
    private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
    private Task _refreshTask = Task.CompletedTask;
    private string? Message;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _timer.AutoReset = true;
        _timer.Elapsed += this.OnTimerElapsed;
        _timer.Enabled = true;

        _refreshTask = this.RefreshData();
    }

    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => _refreshTask = InvokeAsync(this.RefreshData);

    private Task RefreshData()
    {
        this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        this.StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Dispose()
        => _timer.Elapsed -= this.OnTimerElapsed;

}
```

You've questioned the reason for `_refreshTask = this.RefreshData();` and replaced it with:

```cs
 Task.Run(RefreshData);
```

**Firstly**,

don't run `Task.Run` unless you have a very specific reason to do so (and understand why).  You can quickly get into trouble.  Code that interacts with the UI has to run within the UI context thread.  Take this case: the application has switched the timer task to a separate threadpool thread.  Try calling `StateHasChanged` directly in the handler.

```cs
private async void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    await this.RefreshData();        
}

private Task RefreshData()
{
    this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    this.StateHasChanged();
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Run the application without debug and it crashes.  Run in debug mode and you get:

```
The current thread is not associated with the Dispatcher. Use InvokeAsync() to switch execution to the Dispatcher when triggering rendering or component state.'
```

Update `RefreshData`:

```cs
private async Task RefreshData()
{
    this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```

and `await this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)` ensures that `StateHasChanged` is run on the `Dispatcher` thread.

**Secondly**,

`_timer.Elapsed` is a event.  It's fire and forget.  The return type for any event hanlder is `void`.  If you need to run any async code you declare it as `async`.  It becomes a `Task` without an owner, so it's ownership defaults to the application.  Any exceptions are bubbled up to the application and crash it.  You've seen exacly that where `StateHasChanged` was run on the wrong thread and crashed the application.

Go back to the original `OnTimerElapsed` with the direct call to `StateHasChanged`:

```cs
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => _refreshTask = this.RefreshData();

    private Task RefreshData()
    {
        this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        this.StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Run the application without debug and while the counter doesn't update, it doesn't crash: you can navigate to other pages,...  Run in debug mode and you'll get the exception (because the debugger traps exceptions).

**A modification to the original code**

Whilst writing this explanation I realised you use this pattern for all event handlers in the UI to ensure the handler gets run on UI/Dispatcher thread.

```cs
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => _refreshTask = InvokeAsync(this.RefreshData);
```

So the new version looks like this:

```cs
    private void OnTimerElapsed(object? sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        => _refreshTask = InvokeAsync(this.RefreshData);

    private Task RefreshData()
    {
        this.Message = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        this.StateHasChanged();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```