# Blazorise Chart - Setting Chart size + Updating data

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazorise

I'm learning Blazor and using Blazorise Charts for displaying some data. I have 2 things I'm struggling with to do

**Item 1:** How can i speficy a "height" for my chart and centre it to my page. I tried using

```
<div style="width:1000px; height:350px;">
```

But my chart just ends up behind the table. So not sure if there is an inbuilt way to do this?

**Item 2:** I have  my data shwing in a table and that is updating (Thanks to the information here: [Blazor - staging data for clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75701847/blazor-staging-data-for-clients/75704414#75704414)). How do i get my chart to update with the dataset update without "flashing" on redraw? (If it's even possible)

Appreciate any doco's/information.